# How to avoid Modal Bottom Sheet overlap with System Navigation Icons in Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The Material3 Modal Bottom Sheet is currently overlapping with the system navigation buttons. Is there a way to avoid this overlap with the system navigation buttons.

This is the code that I am using for showing modal bottom sheet

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    var sheetOpened by mutableStateOf(false)

    Scaffold() {
       Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
         Button(onClick = { sheetOpened = true }){
              Text("Open Bottom Sheet")  
          }
       }
    }

    if(sheetOpened){
        ModalBottomSheet(onDismissRequest = {sheetOpened = false}){
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(500.dp).background(Color.RED))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Tried putting the Modal Bottom Sheet inside the Scaffold, but that does not work either.

Comment: refer to : https://github.com/TheMelody/AnyPopDialog-Compose

Comment: same issue with me, any solution so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address this issue, inform Jetpack Compose that you'll be handling insets manually. Add the following code to your `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Manually handle all the insets
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            ApplicationTheme {
                // Your Composables
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, calculate the `BottomPadding` of your `BottomModalSheet` using the following approach:

```kotlin
val bottomPadding = WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()
```

Apply this in your `BetterModalBottomSheet` composable as shown in the sample code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BetterModalBottomSheet(
    ...
) {
    val bottomPadding = WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()

    if (showSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            ...
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = bottomPadding)) {
                // Your content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For additional details, refer to this [post](https://medium.com/@giuliopime/modalbottomsheet-and-the-system-navigation-bar-jetpack-compose-6e9bf58e8317).

Comment: I tried the code and also cloned the sample project that had been linked in the blog post. The BetterModalBottomSheet is definately better than the default behaviour, but still, if skipPartiallyExpanded is false, then I can see navigation buttons getting overlapped with the bottom sheet content.
I wish there was a way to avoid this overlapping, by either hiding the navigation buttons when bottom sheet is shown, or making the bottom navigation button bar opaque. please see this screen shot of your demo project for reference. https://ibb.co/Ph4bKnW

Comment: above solution not works for me

Comment: You can tries this code it works for met. 

`ModalBottomSheet(
                        onDismissRequest = { showBottomSheet = false },
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        sheetState = sheetState,
                    ) {
                          ...
                          Spacer(
                            Modifier.windowInsetsBottomHeight(
                                WindowInsets.navigationBars
                            )
                        )
}`

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to add a Spacer at the bottom of ModalBottomSheet content.

```
Spacer(
    Modifier.windowInsetsBottomHeight(
        WindowInsets.navigationBarsIgnoringVisibility
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had called the androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge.enableEdgeToEdge() function in my MainActivity.  This causes your UI to draw behind the bottom navigation and system bar per the documentation found here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge

Deleting the enableEdgeToEdge() call fixed it for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: after enabling the ```edgeToEdge()``` you need to call ```Modifier.navigationBarPadding()``` on your root view.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the height of the Navigationbar in my MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val view = window.decorView
    val insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view)
    val navigationBarHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).bottom }
```

added a Parameter to my Screen

```
MyScreen(
    navigationHeight = navigationHeight
    ...
)
```

and then added the navigatoinBarHeight into my BottomSheet as a WindowBottomInset.

```
ModalBottomSheet(
      windowInsets = WindowInsets(bottom = navigatoinBarHeight)
      ...
){ ... }
```

the close animation is not a 100% percent smooth but other then that is works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest so far...

```
ModalBottomSheet(onDismissRequest = { ... }) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding(),
    ) {
        // bottom sheet content
    }
}
```